# The formula of matrix calculus

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, matrix-calculus, tensors, delta-method

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ is a semi-positive defined symmetric matrix. Then $A^{1/2}$ is well-defined. Now I want to know does there exists a formula for
$$\frac{\partial A^{1/2} }{\partial A}  ?$$
Thanks so much!

BTW, if we find an explicit formula for $\frac{\partial A^{1/2} }{\partial A}$, then does the following approximation holds?
$$B^{1/2} - A^{1/2} = \frac{\partial A^{1/2} }{\partial A} (B - A)+ O(\|B-A\|_2^2) $$
for a proper $p \times p$ matrix $B$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can derrive the derivative using the defintion of the [Frechet Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative)

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Thanks, but I think $\frac{\partial A^{1/2}}{\partial A}$ should be a 4-dimensional tensor rather than a matrix.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter Yeah, Thank you. The matrix calculus is based on Frechet Derivative. But it is too involved for me to calculate the explicit formula of $\frac{\partial A^{1/2}}{\partial A}$ by the standard way to derive a Frechet Derivative. I think there exists an easier way to get the result I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
The square root function is
$$F(S) = S^{1/2}$$
For an SPD matrix, it can be squared, differentiated, vectorized, and inverted to yield
$$\eqalign{
S &= F^2 \\
dS &= dF\,F + F\,dF \\
{\rm vec}(dS)
 &= (F\otimes I + I\otimes F)\;{\rm vec}(dF) \\
 &= (F\oplus F)\;{\rm vec}(dF) \\
ds &= (F\oplus F)\,df \\
df &= (F\oplus F)^{-1}\,ds \\
  &= G\,ds \\
\p{f}{s} &= G \\
}$$
where $(\otimes,\oplus)$ denote the Kronecker product and Kronecker sum, respectively.

In vectorized form, the first order Taylor expansion is
$$\eqalign{
df &\approx G\,ds \quad\implies\quad
f(s+ds)-f(s) &\approx G\,ds \\
}$$
The matrix form requires the gradient as a fourth-order tensor
and the double-dot product
$$\eqalign{
dF &\approx \Gamma:dS \quad\implies\quad
dF_{ij} &\approx \sum_{k}\sum_{\ell}\,\Gamma_{ijk\ell}\;dS_{k\ell} \\
}$$
Converting between the matrix/tensor forms of the gradient $(G/\Gamma)$ is simple but tedious.

In general
$$\eqalign{
G &\in {\mathbb R}^{mn\times pq} \quad\iff\quad
\Gamma \in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n\times p\times q} \\
G_{\alpha\beta} &= \Gamma_{ijk\ell} \\
\alpha &= i+(j-1)\,m \\
\beta &= k+(\ell-1)\,p \\
i &= 1+(\alpha-1)\,{\rm mod}\,m \\
j &= 1+(\alpha-1)\,{\rm div}\,m \\
k &= 1+(\beta-1)\,{\rm mod}\,p \\
\ell &= 1+(\beta-1)\,{\rm div}\,p \\
}$$
However, in this particular case  $\;m=n=q=p$

---

Extend this solution to semi-SPD matrices $(A,B)\,$ by writing them as perturbations $(\lambda,\mu\to 0)$ of $S$ in *symmetric* matrix directions $(X,Y)$
$$\eqalign{
A &= S + \lambda X, \qquad B &= S + \mu Y \\
}$$
Then we can use the SPD solution, with the gradient evaluated at $\Gamma=\Gamma(S),\,$ to write
$$\eqalign{
F(B) - F(S) &\approx \Gamma:\mu Y \\
F(A) - F(S) &\approx \Gamma:\lambda X \\
}$$
Subtraction then yields the expected formula
$$\eqalign{
F(B) - F(A) &\approx \Gamma:(\mu Y - \lambda X) \\
            &\approx \Gamma:(B-A) \\
}$$

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thanks so much!